# What is the difference between a class "Attribute" and "Property"?

Tags: oop, properties, attributes

Can someone carefully describe the nuance between "attributes" and "properties"? I find them used interchangeably at times, and as differentiators at others.

Answer (score -1):

The `attribute` and `property` terms are synonyms in most cases (also `member`, `field`), although `property` is often ([python](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#property), [C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw(v=vs.100).aspx), [pascal](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Property), etc) used to describe the "virtual attribute" which is actually implemented by get/set methods (and `attribute` is used for regular attributes).

For example (python-like pseudocode):

```
class MyClass:

    string first_name_attribute;
    string last_name_attribute;

    @property
    def full_name(self):
        """Getter method returns the virtual "full name"."""
        return self.first_name_attribute + " " + self.last_name_attribute

    @full_name.setter
    def full_name(self, string value):
        """Setter method sets the virtual "full name"."""
        first_name, last_name = value.split(" ")
        self.first_name_attribute = first_name
        self.last_name_attribute = last_name
```

Here we have two "real" attributes - `first_name_attribute` and `last_name_attribute` and a "virtual" property - `full_name`.